# OpenCV does not detect my rectangles with black background

Tags: python, opencv, rectangles

I have rectangles of different sizes on a black background. There is writing inside the rectangles, which I will transform later with `pytesseract`.
But before that, I want to detect the rectangles.

Here is my image:

[image]

And here is my code:

```
image = cv2.imread("test/photo1.png")
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
edged = cv2.Canny(image, 10, 25)
(cnts, _) = cv2.findContours(edged.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
idx = 0
for c in cnts:
    x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(c)
    if w>50 and h>50:
        idx+=1
        new_img=image[y:y+h,x:x+w]
        cv2.imwrite(str(idx) + '.png', new_img)
```

Comment: Your rectangles do not have enough contrast separation with the background to do a good job of isolating them even if you apply gamma enhancement.

Comment: @fmw42 so you said its impossible?

Comment: Not necessarily. But hard.  What was your result? Post the result showing your canny edges. Does that show your boxes? Then look at your contours drawn on the image?  Do some analysis and see if they visually look reasonable or if some further filtering is needed somewhere in the chain of processing.

Comment: I have looked at your canny edge image and it has issues. First, some of the boxes are connected. Second, some of the boxes are not continuous and have large gaps. You would need to have isolated and complete boxes to be able to get the rectangles from contours.